# Accessing SSL Site Using IE7 and Wine

Tags: wine, ie

I am trying to access a IE only site without using a VM. I installed IE7 and got it working on wine 1.5. However, when I go to the site there is a problem with the certificate. If I click to continue anyway, nothing happens. Is there a way to get around this? I tried going to content>certificates but it will not accept the .p12 file I created.

Is there any way to get SSL browsing working using IE7?

Error Log....

```
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0033d598
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0033d390
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=7e2e2b88
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:wininet:InternetConfirmZoneCrossingW (0x100de, L"http://localhost:8000/accelerator", L"https://localhost:8000/accelerator", 0) stub
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x101bf78, 0x101bb78, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x101bf78): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x101bf9c, 0x101bb9c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x101bf9c): stub
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_IDN; STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_UTF8_SERVERNAME_TO_PROXY; STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option INTERNET_OPTION_CODEPAGE (65001): STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_CODEPAGE_PATH; STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_CODEPAGE_EXTRA; STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW INTERNET_OPTION_COOKIES_3RD_PARTY; STUB
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option INTERNET_OPTION_REQUEST_PRIORITY (0): STUB
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
err:wininet:NETCON_secure_connect SSL_connect failed: 12045
fixme:wininet:query_global_option Stub for 98
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x101cd0c, 0x101c90c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x101cd0c): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x101cd30, 0x101c930, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x101cd30): stub
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:apphelp:ApphelpCheckShellObject stub: {9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39} 0x101e510
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:apphelp:ApphelpCheckShellObject stub: {a4741943-6c4b-4cf7-bf44-a0f4207d1330} 0x33b238
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:apphelp:ApphelpCheckShellObject stub: {a4741943-6c4b-4cf7-bf44-a0f4207d1330} 0x33b050
fixme:apphelp:ApphelpCheckShellObject stub: {a4741943-6c4b-4cf7-bf44-a0f4207d1330} 0x33b050
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {6c736db1-bd94-11d0-8a23-00aa00b58e10} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {6c736db1-bd94-11d0-8a23-00aa00b58e10} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:CommitUrlCacheEntryInternal entry already in cache - don't know what to do!
fixme:wininet:GetUrlCacheEntryInfoExW Undocumented flag(s): 100
fixme:wininet:GetUrlCacheEntryInfoExW Undocumented flag(s): 100
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x101d01c, 0x101cc1c, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x101d01c): stub
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:wininet:GetUrlCacheEntryInfoExW Undocumented flag(s): 100
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {1ec4f3c6-2fec-4f6e-b4c2-727668522c3a}
err:ole:ClientIdentity_QueryMultipleInterfaces IRemUnknown_RemQueryInterface failed with error 0x80004002
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:shell:DllGetClassObject failed for CLSID={871c5380-42a0-1069-a2ea-08002b30309d} (Internet)
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x33e564, 0x33e164, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x33e564): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x33e560, 0x33e160, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x33e560): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x33e560, 0x33e160, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x33e560): stub
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:tooltips:TOOLTIPS_WindowProc unknown msg 2007 wp=00000005 lp=00000000
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0033d6a8
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0033d4a0
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=7e2e2b88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bug #26203](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26203) regarding IE 7 not connecting to https://gmail.com was recently fixed. Now, IE 7 can connect. May be that's related. So, try wine-1.5.6 when it comes out.